# Why is my Backbone.js error callback being called even though Rails is supposedly returning a success response?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I am using Backbone.js (version 0.5.3) and am having some trouble with a success callback when [saving a model](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Model-save). It isn't being run, even though the model is successfully saved on the server.

CoffeeScript:

```
console.log 'in switch_private'
console.log "private_entry attribute is currently #{@model.get('private_entry')}"
@model.save {'private_entry': true},
  success: ->
    console.log 'in success'
```

Compiled Javascript:

```
console.log('in switch_private');
console.log("private_entry attribute is currently " + (this.model.get('private_entry')));
return this.model.save({
  'private_entry': true
}, {
  success: function() {
    return console.log('in success');
  }
});
```

Console output:

```
in switch_private
private_entry attribute is currently false
XHR finished loading: "http://localhost:3000/entries/235".
```

I am returning `head :ok` from the update action in Ruby on Rails.

Adding the model and response arguments, so that it's `success: (model, response) ->`, doesn't make a difference. What is going wrong?

EDIT:
As per Trevor Burnham's suggestion, I added an error callback, and it is being run. So what should I be returning from the Ruby on Rails action in order for Backbone to consider the save a success? At the moment I have `head :ok`

EDIT 2: Here is my updated compiled Javascript:

```
var this_view;
this_view = this;
return this.model.save({
  'private_entry': !(this.model.get('private_entry'))
}, {
  success: function(model, response) {
    return console.log('in success');
  },
    error: function(model, response) {
    return console.log('in error');
  }
});
```

Here is the PUT request:

[image]

Comment: What if you add an `error` callback as well? Does it get called?

Comment: I edited the question title. You might want to rewrite it better than that though :/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've run into this.  You can't just return `head :ok` and use Backbone's default behavior. The default Backbone.Sync won't have it.

First of all, if you are doing it in your `create` action, you won't ever know what your `id` is so the model won't be able to update later (which you are doing, because of the "PUT").

Second, in your `update` action, the model won't know that the data is truly in sync if you return `head :ok` so the sync fails again.  But is doesn't matter if you don't have an `id`.

Whatever the case, you need to return something in the body.

Rails scaffolding, by default, returns `head :ok` upon successful `update`.  This doesn't jive with Backbone.  To fix it, return the JSON instead:

```
render json: @entity
```

(where `@entity` is whatever your variable is in the action)

Answer (score 0):

Backbone expects the JSON from the server, and the server returns with a text.

To fix this at client side, set the data type as **text** instead of **json**, and the server is expecting content type as  **json**.

```
options.contentType = 'application/json';
options.dataType = 'text';
```

Your Updated code follows,

```
return this.model.save({'private_entry': !(this.model.get('private_entry'))}, {
     success: function(model, response) {
        return console.log('in success');
     },
     error: function(model, response) {
        return console.log('in error');
     }, 
     contentType : 'application/json',
     dataType : 'text'
});
```

The datatype **text** will not be parsed by Backbone after save.